# Which classes does guice injects objects to?

Tags: guice

Maybe a stupid question, but... I've got a bunch of codebase with classes having @Inject annotations in it. But when the app runs not all objects get injected, some values are null.

So my question is: how does guice know which classes must be processed? Does it traverse object graph somehow?

Comment: Some values of what are null? It's not really clear what you mean...

Comment: Values of objects marked with @Inject annotation. They do not get injected. And since they're not marked as 'optional', I assume that the class the are supposed to be injected to is not processed by guice at all

Comment: It's still not clear where you're trying to inject them. Please give a short but complete example if you possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is not very clear, I'll try to clarify some situations where injection would occur or not occur, so you can see what problem you may face:

1. If class A has @Inject fields, constructor or methods, but is directly instantiated by new somewhere in the code, then it won't normally get injected.
2. Actually in the situation above, injection may occur if the instance was explicitly "marked" for injection in a `Module`, by calling `injectMembers()`.
3. If a class A has @Inject fields, constructor or methods, and it is created by Guice (either by `Injector.getInstance(...)` or by being transitively injected in an instance created by Guice), then it is not possible that injected fields be `null` or injected methods be called with `null` except if parameters have been explicitly declared `@Nullable`. If Guice must inject an object which dependencies can't be resolved then it will throw an exception.

Of course, this is a simplified explanation of how Guice injects (or not) stuff. What is important is point 3. which makes me believe that the instances for injected fields are null have not been created by Guice but directly instantiated with `new`.